# Form Help In Hanamirb (Lotusrb)

Tags: hanami

Does hanami support below code?

```
<%= form_for :question, routes.question_path. method: 'post' do %>
<div class="box-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box-body pad">
       <textarea id="content"></textarea>
    </div>`enter code here`
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And how can I can do it in my template?

Answer (score 0):

Though this is possible, the [official Hanami guide](http://hanamirb.org/guides) discourages it as it has to resort to monkey patching in order to work with the various template engines.

You can read more about it [here](http://hanamirb.org/guides/helpers/forms/).

An alternative approach is to define a single form rendering method in your view, like this:

```
def form
  form_for :question, routes.questions_path, method: 'post' do
    div(class: 'box-body') do
      div(class: 'row') do
        div(class: 'box-body pad') do
          text_area :content, id: 'content'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then, somewhere in your template, you can call it like this to render the form:

```
<%= form %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what do you think if so many block HTML above? You have to convert all HMTL element to Hanami's form helper?

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

And I'm supported by author the best way I want is:

```
<form action="<%= routes.question_path %>" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="<%= csrf_token%>">
<!-- rest of the form goes here -->
</form>
```

Maybe it's help for someone else.